# How to allow for input change in rendered reactjs component? Do I lift up State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I managed to get the values `Hello` and `World` to render on the page, but as of right now, they are not able to be modified. When I click on it, the text cursor appears but any keyboard input isn't recognized. What do I do so that it takes in input (like delete characters, or adding characters)?

[image: Screenshot]

formatoc.js:

```
{...
var props = {
    'name' : 'form',
    'timer' : 1500,
    'callback' : function(id, validity, value) {console.log(id, validity, value);},
    'values': ["hello", "world"],

    'node' : new FormatOC.ArrayNode({"__array__":"unique", "__type__":"string","__minimum__":1,"__maximum__":200,"__component__":"Input"})
}

React.render(React.createElement(ArrayNodeComponent, props), document.getElementById('react-component')); 
...}
```

Array_Node.jsx:

```
 {...
    childChange: function(name, valid, value) {
        // update state

        this.state.values[name] = value;
        this.setState(this.state);

        console.log(name,value);

        // Call parent callback
        this.props.callback(
            this.props.name,
            this.props.newParent.valid(this.state.values),
            this.state.values
        );
    },

        render: function() {
            var that = this;
            console.log("Hello World");

            return (
                <div id = "form">
                {this.props.values.map(function(v, i) {
                    return (
                        <div>
                        {(that.props.node.get().constructor.name === "Parent") ?
                        <ParentComponent
                            name={that.props.name + i}
                            key={i}
                            timer={that.props.timer}
                            callback={that.childChange}
                            values={v}
                            newParent={that.props.node.get()}
                        />
                        :
                        <NodeComponent
                            name={that.props.name + i}
                            key={i}
                            timer={that.props.timer}
                            callback={that.childChange}
                            value={v}
                            newNode={that.props.node.get()}
                        />
                        }
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
                </div>
           )
        }
  ...}
```

Node.jsx:

```
onChange: function(event) {
  that = this;

  var event2 = event.target;

  if (this.state.component === "Input") {

    if (this.timer !== null) {
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
    };
    this.timer = setTimeout(function(){
        that.state.value = event2.value;

        that.props.callback(that.props.name, that.props.newNode.valid(that.state.value), that.state.value);

    }, this.props.timer);
```

UPDATE: When I try to give the fields any text input, the console gives the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined
    at Constructor.childChange (array_node.js:64)
    at Node.js:36`

Comment: Do state lifiting

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN I tried looking it up on google, but am unsure how to lift the state up, do you have any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

**First:**
    childChange: function(name, valid, value) {
        // update state

```
    this.state.values[name] = value; //<- This is a no no
    this.setState(this.state);

...
```

You are directly mutating `state`, which is a big no no. Mutating state directly can cause unintended side effects. That's why there is the `setState()` method. You should be setting state like so:

```
this.setState({values: value});
```

Passing an object that contains the mutation you want to perform.

**Second:**
You are not actually passing this `newParent` item ANYWHERE in your props.

As pointed out by the comments, you should be [lifting state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) instead of trying to hack together some sort of parent/child communication.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be right for me to replace `this.state.values[name] = value;      this.setState(this.state);` with just `this.setState({values: value});`? and as for newParent item, what should I pass it to then?

Comment: @Sam Yes. You should only mutate `state` with `setState()`. As for the `newParent` issue, I think you need to look at where you are creating `NodeComponent` and setting `newNode` instead of `newParent`.

Comment: I just added my `Nodecomponent` code and it's setting newNode and not newParent. Should I change `this.props.newParent.valid(this.state.values),` to `this.props.newNode.valid(this.state.values),` instead?

Comment: @Sam I misspoke. I think the issue is in your `Array_Node.jsx` in your `childChange()` method where you are trying to call the parent's callback. What you need to do, I do not know.

Comment: I got it to work by fixing `this.props.newParent.valid()` to `this.props.node.valid()` but now whenever I call the `.valid()` function, it's always returning false because it is overwriting the array `values` with the String `value`. Is there a way to keep `values` an array and just modify the specific element with what was changed?